# Selected Link class not showing correctly on inet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, highlight

I created a selected link class via java script to highlight the menu link of the page the user is currently on:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('href')==window.location.href){
       $(this).addClass('selected');
  }});
});
</script>
```

Then I edited the link states in css:

```
#topnavindex        {width:17%;float:left;position:fixed;}
#topnavindex ul     {margin:4% 0 0 10%;}
#topnavindex ul li  {font-size:83%;letter-spacing:3px;margin:0 0 1.7% 0;list-style-type:none;}
#topnavindex a      {font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
#topnavindex a:link {color:#8a523e;}
#topnav a:link      {color:#232323;}
#topnav a:visited   {color:#232323;}
#topnav a:hover     {color:#27a896;}
#topnav a.selected  {color:#27a896;}
```

While Chrome and Firefox display my website correctly Internet Explorer ignores the selected link property.

Comment: try document.location instead of window.location.href

Comment: can you post live url?

Comment: no sorry it is not online yet

Comment: Don’t just _assume_ certain variables and element properties contain what you think they do, but _verify_ it using debug outputs.

Comment: `$(this).prop('href')` probably doesn't contain the value you think it does.

Comment: "I created a selected link class via java" — Java and JavaScript are two languages with about as much in common as cars and carpets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to everybody that helped me figure out the problem. The solution was easier than expected.

**I had to change the IE settings ("Advanced"-tab) to "Allow active content to run files on my computer". After that IE could recognize the JavaScripts!**

This problem only occurs because my files were saved locally. On a live webpage the scripts will most likely work for the audience without changing the IE settings.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way you are referencing the anchors (through a parent element) the styling from those CSS rules is taking preference over your "selected" class.

Referencing your "selected" class as (through the parent element in the same way as the other rules are):

```
#topnav a.selected
```

should make you able to remove the "!important" tag

Looking at you're JS, you'll probably want to be more specific on your opening selector than just $("a").each. This will end up looping through every single link you have across your site that you might have in the future. You could simply add your #topnav in there to make it only look through the relevant anchors.

```
$("topnav a").each...
```

Comment: Referencing the class helped me to get rid of the "!important" tag, thx. I will try the rest now

Comment: Did being able to remove the !important tag solve your IE woes? what version of IE are you running and having issues with out of interest?

Comment: Alright. My problem with IE is still not solved. Selected links are still not highlighted in IE. I do not have any issues with IE apart from this one.

Comment: Since the !important-tag had nothing to do with it I updated my question

Comment: I am running IE 11

Comment: Have you checked whether the class is present on the anchors?

Comment: I am kinda new to this, sorry. So what is an anchor and how can i check this?

Comment: Anchor = hyperlink, it's the text name for an <a> html element. 

Open up your website in internet explorer, right click on the anchor (hyperlink) that should have the "selected" class on. Go to "Inspect Element". This will then open up what is called "developer tools". The element that you have right clicked on should be highlighted blue where it shows the HTML output of the page. Check the classes on the highlighted element and see if your "selected" class is on it.

Comment: <a href="begleitungsformen.html">BEGLEITUNGSFORMEN</a>, it says

Comment: Okay, you're jQuery isn't adding the selected class to the element. .prop() is usually used for Boolean values (true / false) try changing your $(this).prop('href') to $(this).attr("href")

Comment: Infact, scrap that. .attr() is going to take the direct href string i.e. "begleitungsformen.html", where "window.location.href" is taking the whole URL so they will never match. change it back to .prop("href") Go back into "Developer tools", go to the console tab at the top and paste your jQuery inside your script tag into the grey area at the bottom of the console tab and click the green play icon. If it does what it is supposed to do, you have some other underling issue